# SSO oauth2 cannot execute after if statement Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I make login SSO everything is ok but when I click login, it cannot redirect and continue to my default page as admin role, I check in my code maybe the error in header, because after redirect to authUrl, the next line code is stop and not execute again

```
public function loginsso(){
     $session = session();
$model = new \App\Models\UserModel();
 $provider = new Keycloak([
        'authServerUrl' => 'https://sso.example.com',
        'realm' => 'test',
        'clientId' => 'sensor',
        'clientSecret' => 'sensor',
        'redirectUri' => 'sensor'
    ]);

       if ($this->request->getGet('code') === null) {
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $session->set('oauth2state', $provider->getState());
    $oauth=$session->get('oauth2state');
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    
    // Tidak ada pernyataan 'return' di sini, membiarkan eksekusi berlanjut
}

     elseif ($this->request->getGesst('code') !== null) {
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $_GET['code']]);
    $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);
      $where2 = ['niplama' => $user->getNip()];
      $status = $model->cek_login($where2)->getRow();

      $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);
      $logout_url = $provider->getLogoutUrl();
      $d = $model->get_pegawai_by_id($user->getNip());
      $lvl = $model->get_lvl($user->getNip());
      //echo $user->getUsername();
      echo $lvl;
      if($d){
            $session = session();
            $session->set('user_id', $d['id']);
            $session->set('role', $d['role']);
            $session->set('username', $user->getUsername());
            $session->set('niplama', $user->getNip());
      if ($d['role'] === 'admin') {
                    return redirect()->to('/inputrpd');
                } elseif ($d['role'] === 'operator') {
                    return redirect()->to('/chartview');
                }
        }else{
          "tidak terdaftar di database";
        }

  } else {
  // Handle ketika 'code' tidak ditemukan
  echo "Parameter 'code' tidak ditemukan di URL.";
   }

      
         }
```

Comment: What is `($this->request->getGet('code') === null)` evaluating to?

Comment: yes i'm evaluating if there is no code then execute , and then save the code

Comment: I understand that. The question is whether at that point it enters the `if` or the `else`?

Comment: first if to save the authurl, and then continue to elseif to get the token

Comment: If it enters the `if`, then it redirects to the `$authUrl`. can you tell me what `$authUrl`'s value is?